# Placeholder is not working in PrimeFaces p:inputText

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to use PrimeFaces inputText text box to get user input. Even I add placeholder attribute, the text is not appearing in the text box. Is there any library I need to include for this? below is my jsf page.

```
 <ui:composition template="/template/master-layout.xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
     <ui:define name="head">  test header </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="meta">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{HomeBean.initPage}"></f:event>
        </f:metadata>
    </ui:define>
      <ui:define name="mainContainer">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <p:inputText placeholder="Your ID" styleClass="form-control service-input-border" maxlength="20" id="Id"
               value="#{homeBean.Id}"></p:inputText>
         </div>
        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apostolos answer is good, but I prefer using passthrough attributes. You can use them **if you're using JSF >= JSF 2.2**.

Just use new namaspace `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough` and use any HTML attribute you like (e.g. any which is not added to the input/compoment). In your case it will be `placeholder`.

```
<ui:composition template="/template/master-layout.xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">    

<!-- ... -->

<p:inputText pt:placeholder="Your ID" styleClass="form-control service-input-border"
    maxlength="20" id="Id" value="#{homeBean.Id}" />
```

You can read more about passthrough attributes [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm) and [here](https://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/08/08/jsf22-html5/).

Comment: interesting. i didnt know that. i was using the classic `<f:passThroughAttribute name="XXX" value="XXX" />` tag. upvoting!

Comment: @Apostolos yeah, those are the same in the end, but `f:passThroughAttribute` is longer and much more verbose ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Youw should use the `watermark` tag for displaying placeholders.

```
<p:inputText styleClass="form-control service-input-border" maxlength="20" id="Id" value="#{homeBean.Id}"></p:inputText>
<p:watermark for="Id" value="Your ID" id="watermark" />
```

See the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/watermark.xhtml) too

Comment: Still same. I tried this. That's why I want to know any lib I missed.

Comment: i tried it before posting it as an answer and it was working. no extra libs. be careful with the ids. is `for` refering to the correct `id`?